# Vue.js: anonymous function with parameter in v-on:event or @event

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to execute a simple function after an event is emitted from the child component. The problem is the child component emits data that I need as a parameter for my function.

How can I inject the parameter and run the function in one line in the component?

```
<div v-on:posted="runTask"> </div>
```

Or

```
<div @posted="runTask"> </div>
```

Important: I would like it to fit in the template (`v-on:event` or `@event`) because I want to keep the component in the PHP blade template.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For anonymous functions with parameter, use:

```
<div v-on:click="return function(data) { console.log(data); }"> </div>
```

Or in more concise ES6:

```
<div v-on:click="(data) => { console.log(data); }"> </div>
```

**Note:** You can use any variable name instead of `data`. Vue.js will inject the data emitted with the event into that variable name.

Comment: This is really helpful. I knew that react can do this. Didn't know Vue can, too. Thanks!

Comment: How do you access the event in data variable?